How to disable autocorrect in google search python API
I am trying to search certain prompts on google using its python library. However, I am getting a response after autocorrect.
Is there any way to disable autocorrect while using google search API like below
import google 
from googlesearch import search

search(my_prompt, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2)

I tried looking at the API doc but did not get an answer.
